# Add a Custom post type custom field to WordPress Screen options

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a created a custom meta box with field called model_num using CMB2 for my custom Taxonomy. Is it possible to show that field under WordPress Screen Options

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think CMB2 does not support Screen Options location.

So far following locations are supported by CMB2:

https://github.com/CMB2/CMB2/wiki/Box-Properties#context

> Post edit screen contexts include 'normal', 'side', and 'advanced'. (More Info)
>
> For placement in locations outside of a metabox (but in the
>   post/custom-post-type screen), other options include: **'form_top',
>   'before_permalink', 'after_title', 'after_editor'**

You may read more instructions in this regard e.g. to remove the metabox or styles when not shown on default locations:

https://github.com/CMB2/CMB2/wiki/Box-Properties#context

So that is limitation of CMB2.

However to add more settings to Screen Options please read this codex page for ideas:

https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_screen_option